# Is it possible to increase Containerd log limit greater than 16K?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

Our RKE2 environment uses Containerd as runtime. We have appllications that writes 50-60 KB lines to stdout and containerd is splitting this stdout logs to separated lines. Is it possible to increase character or size limit of log lines?

RKE2 version: 2.6.5
Kubernetes Version: v1.21.6+rke2r1

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to increase this log limit, but docker truncate the log when its size is bigger than 16KB without adding `\n`, so if you use a tool to collect the log (ex: Fluented with concat plugin), you can re-aggregate these messages:

```
<filter **>
    @id filter_concat
    @type concat
    key log
    use_first_timestamp true
    multiline_end_regexp /\n$/
    separator ""
</filter>
```